# Equations on Free Groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

I was trying to read an old [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-096-03/S0002-9947-1960-0151503-8/S0002-9947-1960-0151503-8.pdf) concerning equations on free groups and immediately came to a puzzling statement which made me wonder whether I am fundamentally misunderstanding something or if I am unaware of some notational convention.
[image]

The "trivial example" that if $w(x)=xa_1 a^{-1} a_1^{-1}$, the solutions $u$ are all elements $a_1^v$ where $v$ is an integer does not make sense to me. Firstly, what is $a$ as it was never formally defined? Apparently we are working with the free group on $\{x,a_1,\ldots, a_r\}$ and considering solutions in the free subgroup generated by $\{a_1,\ldots, a_r\}$. So, is $a$ just an arbitrary element in that free subgroup? If so, I do not see how the equation could hold for $x=a_1^v$. It seems to me that $w(x)=1$ and $x=a_1^v$ requires $a$ to be $a_1^{-v}$. But, I thought that the only variable is $x$, with the other letters representing fixed group elements.

What am i missing?

Comment: I think $a=x$..

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Also, I agree with @DavidA.Craven.

Comment: @Shaun Noted for the future. I included it this time because my concern that there might be a typo in the original manuscript caused worry that people would comment something like "are you sure you typed that out correctly?"

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Hopefully that is it; makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: That makes sense, @Mithrandir. What you could have done is use "*sic*" or highlight the $a$ by colouring it, like $\color{red}a$.